# Incorrect external monitor resolution detected, true resolution not available

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution

I have a [BenQ EX3501R](https://www.benq.com/en/monitor/video-enjoyment/ex3501r/specifications.html) monitor connected by HDMI to my MacBook Pro, which is a Early 2015 model.

The issue being that OS X gets the resolutions completely wrong - the monitors native resolution is 3440x1440 but it switches it to 6720x3780!

Alt-clicking the 'Scaled' radio box does not list the correct resolution.

For further confusion, a Mid 2012 15' MacBook Pro connecting to the same monitor via the same HDMI cable works fine. The only notable difference is that one has a GeForce chip, where as mine is Intel Iris.

Both are running latest Mojave 10.14.1

any ideas of a way to proceed?

[image: graphic info]
[image: suggested resolution]
[image: osx-info]
[image: display-settings]

Comment: what you did not tell us how does the picture looks like at 6720x3780!

Comment: did it work on the 2015 before Mojave upgrade ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 it rendered, but everything was tiny and pixelated. didn't look good. I got the monitor after i upgraded the OS X to Mojave

Comment: Having the same issue with a dell u3818dw. Native resolution is 3,840 x 1,600 pixels but that option is not available (even with alt-click).

Comment: Ultimately I restarted the 'dock' that I was using and the correct resolution appeared. If you're using an adapter or dock (which, it's a mac so of course you are), unhook it/power it off and back on.

Comment: My Mac is (arguably) the last of the real Pro Mac's, with actual useful ports :) so I never need a dock, imagine that...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If so, how? If not, what is the cable/adapter situation between the laptop and the monitor? Straight HDMI->HDMI? How long is the cable?

Comment: I have the same issue with a Huawei MateView, which has a native res of 3840 x 2560 (@2x is 1920 x 1280), which is 3:2. When connecting to a MacBook Air 2005 via MiniDP to HDMI, the Mac thinks the monitor has 6720 x 3740 (wrong aspect ratio, too!), and I cannot even tweak it with SwitchResX. On a Mac Mini 2018 via direct HDMI it works fine, but thru a TB3-to-TB2 adapter, then to HDMI, I get the wrong 6720 res again, So, seems to be a TB2 issue. Next I need to try a MiniDP-to MiniDP cable on the MacBook Air bc a TB2 cable (even though it's using the same connectors) doesn't work at all.

Comment: Update: A MiniDP-to-MiniDP cable doesn't help, either. I still get the wrong (too-large) res and it won't offer the correct ones. So it's probably a hardware problem with this older Mac's graphics system.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the Monitor profile used by Mojave that needs repair.

Open the Color sync Utility in the Utility Folder

[image: color sync utility]

Verify you Monitor is showing correctly under devices.

Use the Profile First Aid.

Comment: you might be onto something, 53 profiles are needing repair, and on clicking Repair, it said only 2 were fixed. sigh. "The file is locked. Could not be fixed." Is there a way to run this as root?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with DELL U3818DW. There is a chance that your graphics card doesn't support HDMI 2.0

> NOTE: If you do not see 3840 x 1600 as an option:
>   Check you graphics driver. Ensure you have the latest graphics drivers installed.
>   Check your HDMI setting. U3818DW ships with HDMI 2.0 as default setting. If your graphics card only supports only HDMI 1.4, 3840 x 1600 will not appear in under the resolution table. Do the following to get 3840 x 1600 on the resolution table.
>   From the Monitor OSD > Input Source
>   On your current HDMI connection (e.g. HDMI1 or HDMI2), press and hold Confirm button for 8 seconds to switch monitor from HDMI 2.0 to HDMI 1.4.

[Instuctions for DELL U3818DW](https://www.dell.com/support/article/ru/ru/rudhs1/sln307029/u3818dw-monitor-troubleshooting-guide?lang=en)

After doing the above in the monitor's settings (switching from HDMI 2.0 to HDMI 1.4) the issue was gone.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if my monitor has equivalent settings